# when variances are unequal between groups. (Welch ANOVA in r)

Tags: anova, heteroscedasticity, generalized-least-squares

I want to know why the results are different between

```
oneway.test()
```

and

```
gls()
```

I assume the variance are different across groups. Here is an example.

```
set.seed(1232)
pop = data.frame(group=c("A","B","C"),
                 mean=c(1,2,5),
                 sd=c(1,3,4))
d = do.call(rbind, rep(list(pop),13))
d$x = rnorm(nrow(d), d$mean, d$sd)
```

The result from oneway.test() is following

```
oneway.test(x ~ group, data=d, var.equal=FALSE)
One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)
data:  x and group
F = 12.7127, num df = 2.000, denom df = 19.055, p-value = 0.0003107
```

where the p value is 0.0003107 and F is 12.7127.

But when I try to build a model using a specific variance structure (sample are independent and within group variance are not equal), I get a different result from gls().

```
mod.gls = nlme::gls(x ~ group, data=d,weights=varIdent(form= ~ 1 | group))
anova(mod.gls)
Denom. DF: 36 
            numDF  F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1 16.57316  0.0002
group           2 13.15743  0.0001
```

Now this time, the p value of group is 0.0001 and F is 13.15743.

I want to know why the results are different.